# Debian upgrade Nginx from source

Tags: nginx, debian, source, make

I've installed Nginx 1.2.1 from apt-get install in my Debian 7 instance (Google Compute Engine).

In order to install Pagespeed mod for Nginx, I will need to compile Nginx from the source code to add pagespeed module.

But I have difficulties installing Nginx 1.4.2 from source. After ./configure .. make and make install, I reboot the machine, but Nginx is still 1.2.1.

Please advise how to upgrade Nginx from source without re-configure the whole LEMP system.

Thanks for advance.
Best Regards,
Tran

Answer (score 3):

I suggest recompiling the package in debian way:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rebuilding-ubuntu-debian-linux-binary-package/

Just get the source from debian repository, add required module and build a new package. Version 1.4.1 is available in jessie.

Your update is not successful probably because make install does not put nginx binary in /usr/sbin/nginx.